# using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

Tags: visual-studio

Simply trying to add 
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
to an existing VS Community 2017 project so I can implement Unit testing.

I've googled and the solution seems to be to right click your project and 'Add>Reference'

But when I do so I see the attached under Assemblies 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IEth.jpg

(No Framework Assemblies were found on the machine.

Can any VS gurus help?

Comment: Try adding this as a NuGet package rather than a reference. Right click the project, manage NuGet packages, install, from All, search for it, install it in your project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference in VS.
In Nuget Package Manager search for and install MSTest.TestFramework. This will allow you to "using" Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting ..

Good luck

Comment: I also needed to add MSTest.TestAdapter and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk packages for my tests to be "found"